# Referencing containing fieldset in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, fieldset

I have a custom signature directive using a canvas. My scaffolding is below:

```
angular
    .module('app.orders')
    .directive('eSignature', eSignature);

function eSignature() {
   var directive = {
     restrict: 'EA',
     templateUrl: 'app/orders/signature/signature.directive.html',
     replace: true,
     scope: {
       ngModel: '='
     },
     link: linkFunc,
     controller: SignatureController,
     controllerAs: 'vm',
     bindToController: true
   };

   return directive;
}
```

This directive will occasionally be wrapped in a containing fieldset using the ngDisabled directive. I want to be able to reference the fieldset so that I know when it's enabled/disabled to reflect styling of my element appropriately. I've tried referencing the form controller in the link function with

```
require: '^form'
```

but this doesn't give me the information I need. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: have you added `require: '^form'` in  directive? and add your `linkFunc`

Comment: Yes, this is what I was trying to explain. From my understanding, accessing the form controller doesn't show me the fieldsets, moreover even if it did, I don't know how I would be sure my component is within a specific one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a solution. Please let me know if there is a cleaner way to go about it.

I ended up creating a fieldset directive.

```
angular
    .module('app.orders')
    .directive('fieldset', fieldset);

function fieldset() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: linkFunc
    };

    return directive;
}

function linkFunc(scope, element, attrs) {
    attrs.$observe('disabled', function (newVal) {
        element.find('e-signature').attr('disabled', !!newVal || newVal === '');
    });
}
```

In this directive, I observe it's "disabled" attribute. I check for both !!newVal (to validate against disabled='disabled' and disabled=true) as well as newVal === '' (for disabled=''), all of which are valid values to declare a tag as disabled.

Then, with angular's [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite), I control the disabled attribute of my newly creative directive.

**NOTE**: I removed the replace property in my eSignature directive in order to reference it by it's tag since according to jqLite's docs, its *find* is "limited to lookups by tag name."

```
function eSignature() {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateUrl: 'app/orders/signature/signature.directive.html',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    controller: SignatureController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true
  };

  return directive;
}
```

Lastly, I used css (written in Less, but also is valid in Sass) to disable my canvas element

```
e-signature:disabled, e-signature[disabled="disabled"] {
   canvas, div[pw-canvas] {
     pointer-events: none;
     cursor: not-allowed;
   }
   canvas {
     opacity: 0.55;
   }
}
```

Hopefully this is help to anyone in the future!